# Logrotate failing with `No data available` error

Tags: logging, ubuntu-14.04, log-files, logrotate, log-rotation

I'm using `logrotate` for various log rotation tasks, including rotating log files for the postgresql pooling utility `pgbouncer`.

`pgbouncer` logs expansively - I accumulate many GBs in a couple of days - thus I changed its config in `logrotate.d` to `size 100M` and `rotate 5`, hoping that this would limit pgbouncer's logs to an aggregate of 500MB.

I then ran `logrotate -f /var/logrotate.conf` to force the changes. The command took a good 10 minutes to give me output. The output was `error writing to /var/log/postgresql/pgbouncer.log.1: No data available`. I.e. rotation failed for pgbouncer. How do I fix this? Please advise.

---

p.e. If I do `tail -f pgbouncer.log`, I see a ton of log lines being generated in real time, so logging is still going on. Moreover, `pgbouncer.log.1` does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have enough disk space for log rotation to actually create all the rotated log files dictated by my .conf file. I truncated the log file, tried again, and it worked.